# Using Interop.WMPLib.dll in mono # linux

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, archlinux, wmplib

i'm developing an application in windows using visual studio 2010 and c#... now i wanna compile this application in mono (installed on windows) and then run my application on archlinux (with monoframework).

This application use Interop.WMPLib.dll and there isn't in mono framework... Can i reference WMP in mono? What are alternatives?

Thanks a lot!
Enrico